# Does the String pool take local variables?

Tags: java, string, multithreading, synchronization

I believed the String pool abandoned local Strings when their methods completed

Yet:

```
public class TestPool implements Runnable{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public void run() {
        String str= "hello";
        synchronized(str){

            try {
                System.out.print(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                Thread.sleep(500);
                System.out.print(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            }

            catch(InterruptedException e){

            }

        }
         }
        public static void main(String []args){
            new Thread(new TestPool(),"A").start();
            new Thread(new TestPool(),"B").start();
        }
    }
```

According to the whizlabs' guide, this code is correcly synchronizing its threads based on a local String. The output will always be AABB or BBAA. Why? Why does the str String outlive its local declaration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because both local declarations of str point to the same interned String literal "hello".  Interned strings are constants and maintained in a pool.  They do not have a typical lifecycle and thus do not get garbage collected when there aren't anymore references.

This would not be the case if the declaration was

```
String str = new String("hello");
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `str` is only a local variable, but it is pointing into the string pool; on two successive invocations of the method, `str` will be pointing to the same place in the pool, so you are still synchronizing on the same object.

If your code was

```
String str = new String("hello");
```

then you would indeed be synchronizing on a local object.

Answer (score 2):

`str` is a local variable whose scope is limited to the `run()` method it's defined in. For different Threads, there should be different `str`s.

**However,** both of those different local `str`s point at the String "hello", which, as a compile-time constant, is *interned*. That is, a single instance of a String with that content is produced in a pool, and anything which points to the same run of characters will be pointed at that same object.

It's as if you had created a static instance of such a String.

Comment: I should write that more often :) Hope my final text also merits the vote.

Comment: The reference is a local variable, but the String it points to isn't. See what happens when you change the declaration to String str = new ("hello");

Comment: That's what I said. Looks like you got it! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not that the string pool is taking local variables, it's that `"hello"` is only stored once and reused (since Strings are immutable).

Try this inside your synchronized block, both threads will print the same value, indicating you have the same object.

```
System.out.println( str.hashCode() );
```

Comment: I think you're contradicting yourself. The "hello" String is stored in the String pool. There's nowhere else for it to be stored.

Comment: hashCode is not reliable for testing for same Object. ... 1) different Strings can result in the same hashCode ("10" and "0O") ... 2) 2 distinct Strings (a != b) with the same content (a.equals(b)) must return the same hashCode